# PayPal IPN not sending to website from sandbox

Tags: paypal-ipn

I am using paypal IPN. I set the notify URL and at one point it was working fine. I went ahead and finished up the site im building, put it on a live server and now the IPN is not sending to the site. I have used the IPN Simulator and my website receives the notification fine. I manually go to the notify url and my website runs the code. The actual transaction completes fine it just doesn't send the notification to the website. The Cancel and Success URLs work fine. I have made sure the IPN is turned on in my sandbox. Lastly, I have logs within the notify url page that show info when I go to the page through the above but nothing shows when I do a transaction. I have read through at least 30 posts on this site and have exhausted all resources so im hoping someone has another idea.

The notification from PayPal Sandbox just does not send during the transaction, I have eliminated what I think is every possibility. Anyone run into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the delivery status in the IPN history?  It could be that your IPNs are getting queued.  That's been happening to me the last few days.  Log into your sandbox account and click "History" in the overview section on top.  Then scroll down and click "IPN History."  It should show the status of each IPN.  If the status is queued, I don't think there is much you can do besides wait.  It has taken more than 24 hour for Paypal Sandbox to process some of my recent IPNs.

Comment: Thanks @Pennywise 9 hours after all my testing the site received all the notifications. I was not aware of a delay. I had assumed it was PP sandbox as it has never worked 100% so I went ahead made it live and tested it and it worked fine. You are right on the delay though, I cannot find anything on it so hopefully this helps someone in the future.